# Check if HTML attr is present in ul list on_change(checkbox)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to know how I can **see if HTML attribute of a checkbox element (like cat here) is in a `<ul>` list of elements**, using jQuery.

```html
// checkbox like so, cat is the string I want
<input type="checkbox" name="country_code" data-cat="city_inf">
```

```html
// list of elements containing my categories (when one element of it is checked in HTML code)
<ul id="sortable" class="ul_drag_el">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Cat name 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Cat name 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>etc..</li>
</ul>
```

And another question is, if I want to count how much elements from a category are checked to display/hide `li` category name, should I do a list of every checked element by their name or can I just do a counter (still in jQuery).

For the moment I only have this in jQuery but I'm really lost on how to start.

```js
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
        let text_to_append = "<li className='ui-state-default'><span className='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-'>"
        text_to_append += $(this).attr('name');
        text_to_append += "</span>"

        if(this.checked){
            $('.ul_drag_el').append(text_to_append)
        }  
    })
```

**edit**: it finally works with it

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
        let this_name = $(this).attr('data-cat')

        let text_to_append = "<li className='ui-state-default' data-cat='"
        text_to_append += this_name
        text_to_append += "'><span className='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-'>"
        text_to_append += this_name
        text_to_append += "</span>"

        if(this.checked){
            $('.ul_drag_el').append(text_to_append)
        }else{
            $('#sortable li').each(function(){
                if($(this).attr('data-cat') == this_name){
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: For custom attributes you should be using `data-`, e.g. `data-cat`

Comment: it is a web clause ? I mean good habit ?

Comment: Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Do you want to check if the `data-cat` attribute is included in the `ul` 's Cat name?

Comment: I want to see if any `li` in the `ul` list has the data-cat attribute when changing value of my checkbox. Like so, if I'm checking it, I append a `<li>` to the `<ul>` list. And if I'm unchecking it, I need to remove the `<li>` corresponding to the `data-cat`'s checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add data-attribute as well to your `li` tag which will have value of `data-cat` .Then , whenever checkbox is checked you can simply check if that `data-cat` already present or not using `$("#ul").find("[data-name=" + $(this).data('cat') + "]").length == 0)` if yes just remove them or add new `li`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  //check if checkbox is checked & that doesn't exist inside ul
  if ((this.checked) && ($("#ul").find("li[data-name=" + $(this).data('cat') + "]").length == 0)) {
    let text_to_append = "<li className='ui-state-default' data-name='" + $(this).data('cat') + "'><span className='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-'>"
    text_to_append += $(this).attr('name');
    text_to_append += "</span></li>"
    $('.ul_drag_el').append(text_to_append)
  } else {
    //remove them
    $("li[data-name=" + $(this).data('cat') + "]").remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="city_inf" data-cat="city_inf">
<input type="checkbox" name="abcs" data-cat="abcs">
<ul id="sortable" class="ul_drag_el">

</ul>
```

Comment: is `$("#ul").find("[data-name=" + $(this).data('cat') + "]"` searching in the whole ul element ?

Comment: and even others I guess, like ul > li > span ?

Comment: you can be more specific add `find("li[data-name=" + $(this).data('cat') + "]" ..`

Comment: Thanks Swati, find function will help me a lot. Didn't knew it was existing.

Comment: You can learn more about this [here](https://api.jquery.com/find/) . Also , go through [Tree Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', '.country_code', function () {
    var cat = "";
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        cat = $(this).attr('data-cat');
    }
    $('#sortable li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-cat') == cat) {
            $(this).show()
        } else {
            $(this).hide()
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Make it as a code presentation by selecting all and click on `{}` for nice view.And also don't forgot to give class name as `'.country_code'`.

Comment: i was just seeing your code is it relavant to question asked

Comment: Well, for the moment I think in append/remove `li` to list but if it works with .hide() and .show(), that could be a solution. But that actually doesn't work.